# Remove tag from words after using postagger in java

Tags: java, string, nlp

I used Stanford's NLP postagger to tag the nouns,adjectives in my program.

```
    interest_NN 
    bui_NNS 
    ground_VBP
     avail_NN 
    respond_NN
     detail_NN 
    like_IN 
    quickli_NNS
    current_JJ
```

Now I have to select only those words which has tags _NN,_NNS,_JJ and also remove these tags from the words.

```
    quickli
    current
    avail
```

I tried like this to remove the -NN tag from the word. But It removed first 2words tags and got exception from it

```
           while(tagread.hasNext())
           {
        String s=tagread.next();

        int flag=1;
        jTextArea2.append("\n" +s.toLowerCase());


        String ofInterest2 = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("_NN"));


         for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
             if(s.equals(ofInterest2))
                 {
                 flag=0;
                 }
         }
         if(flag!=0)
         {
             System.out.println(ofInterest2);

         }
    }
```

Exception:

```
 java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
```

So whats wrong with my approach? or how to proceed further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use string methods to remove tagger text; use the NLP's API to extract the part-of-speech for comparisons.

Generate a `List` of `TaggedWord` objects then use the [TaggedWord API](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/ling/TaggedWord.html) to extract the part-of-speech directly:

```
// Call the API to parse your sentence.
List<TaggedWord> words = tagger.tagSentence( ... );

// For each word tagged in the sentence...
for( TaggedWord word : words ) {
  String tag = word.tag();

  // Check the part-of-speech directly, without having to parse the string.
  if( "NN".equalsIgnoreCase( tag ) ) {
    System.out.printf( "%s is a noun\n", word.word() );
  }
}
```

See also Stanford's NLP APIs:

- http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/ling/Word.html
- http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/ling/TaggedWord.html
- http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/tagger/maxent/MaxentTagger.html

To check for a noun, you should avoid the following:

```
if( "NN".equalsIgnoreCase( tag ) ) {
  System.out.printf( "%s is a noun\n", word.word() );
}
```

This is because parts-of-speech can be tagged in many of ways (e.g., NN, NNS). You can use a regular expression or [`startsWith`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29).

You should ask the author of `TaggedWord` to provide an `isNoun`. `isVerb`, `isNounPlural` and other such methods. That said, yes, you can use a regex to match the strings. I also use `startsWith` in my code to check for nouns because it is faster than a regular expression. For example:

```
if( tag != null && tag.toUpperCase().startsWith( "NN" ) ) {
  System.out.printf( "%s is a noun\n", word.word() );
}
```

To be truly OO, inject a subclass of TaggedWord for the tagger to use. The subclass would then expose the `isNoun` method.

Comment: can you provide simple example? I used Standford postagger. Give me some NLProcessing API's. thanks

Comment: After your suggestions well I try to do another way. Like using regex to check the end of the string like ending like _NNP,_VRB etc then remove that entire string using replace all. is this method is correct?

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf` returns -1 when the argument you provide can't be found in the String.  On this line:

```
String ofInterest2 = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("_NN"));
```

`s.indexOf` probably didn't find "_NN" in the string `s`.  Then when you ask for a substring from `0` to `-1` of s, that doesn't make sense so you get an Exception.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to take the substring of the entire text "ground_VBP", but you pass in the result of `s.indexOf("_NN")`.  The substring is not found, so it returns `-1`.  But `-1` is not a valid index into the `substring` function, so `substring` threw the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` you have reported.

You should only take the substring if the `indexOf` method returns something 0 or greater (i.e. it was found).

Comment: Is there any better method apart from my approach?

Comment: There may be a "postagger" method to do this; I don't know.  I am not familiar with it.  I just saw the reason why your approach caused a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.